# How to verify if the product code and product version have been updated using MSBuild support for Installshield

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, installshield

I'm trying to build an InstallShield project with MSBuild and TFS 2013. I followed the steps required to override the product code as indicated [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951003/upgrading-tfs-build-template-to-automate-installed-shield-project). First, I created an .isproj file and managed to generate the installer successfully. However, the product code seems not to be changed. I check the file setup.ini and noticed that the Product GUID still the same as the value of Product Code in the .ism file. 
Is there a way to verify that the product code and product version have been changed?

**@Update**

It worked finally, I was able to verify the newly generated product code using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Chris's script works perfectly as well!

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an InstallShield bug.  Can you extract the MSI and see if the ProductCode is changed in the Property table?

Comment: I just tried your example below but it still does not work: when I open the setup.ini file, the product GUID is intact. However, when I edit the .ism file and build it using IS interface, then it works. The product code changes. Please note that I'm using the trial version for now. Would it be because of this? As per this [**page**](http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/INFO/Q200900), the trial version produces a setup.exe file instead of .msi. I tried to check out the property table with Orca, but it doesn't parse .exe files.

Comment: When you run the setup.exe it'll extract the MSI to a temp directory.  Grab it from there and examine it with ORCA.  If the ProductCode is correct in the MSI but incorrect in the INI then this is an IS bug and you'll have to update the ISM prior to building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

In my ISM release view (build tab)  I set the Release Location to \Installer instead of   In my Path Variables I declare an ISBUILDDIR path variable and give it a default value of ISProjectDataFolder

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <MSIProductVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER), "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+"))</MSIProductVersion>
        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
        <InstallShieldProductConfiguration>ProductConfigName</InstallShieldProductConfiguration>
        <InstallShieldRelease>ReleaseName</InstallShieldRelease>
        <InstallShieldProductVersion>$(MSIProductVersion)</InstallShieldProductVersion>
    <MSIProductCode>$([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpper())</MSIProductCode>
    <InstallShieldBuildDependsOn>PreBuild</InstallShieldBuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <InstallShieldPathVariableOverrides Include="$(OutDir)">
            <PathVariable>ISBUILDDIR</PathVariable>
        </InstallShieldPathVariableOverrides>
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="$(MSIProductCode)">
      <Property>ProductCode</Property>
    </InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <InstallShieldProject Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).ism"/>
        <InstallShieldMergeModulePath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MSM"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="PreBuild">
    <Exec Command="attrib -s -h -r  /s &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\*.*&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" ContinueOnError="true"/>
  </Target>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\InstallShield\2012\InstallShield.targets"/>
</Project>
```