# Using TFS (2013) to automatically update InstallShield (2014) Product Code

Tags: tfs, installshield

I am looking to update the Product Code Automatically through the build process.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if the product code and product version have been updated using MSBuild support for Installshield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625594/how-to-verify-if-the-product-code-and-product-version-have-been-updated-using-ms)

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield's has MSBuild support where the .isproj  file can be updated to autogenerate a random guid and pass it into the compile.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSIProductCode>$([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpper())</MSIProductCode>
</PropertyGroup>

<InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="$(MSIProductCode)">
  <Property>ProductCode</Property>
</InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
```

If you aren't using MSBuild (which everyone should be in my opinion)  then here's the ISCmdBld[.exe reference](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/ISCmdBldParam.htm).  You'll want to use the -z option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.   I am not to familiar with the .isproj.  What is the best way to create that and implement into my build template.

Comment: I use .ism projects to build the installer

Comment: ism is what gets built.  It's not what you use to build it.   .isproj is to .csproj as .ism is to .cs.   .ISPROJ supports msbuild. It sounds like you are just using IsCmdBld.exe.  It's really hard to answer your question if you don't give any description of your build environment.

Comment: I will try to provide more detail.  We have InstallShield Standalone on our build server.   I am using the TFS Build template with an invokeprocess to build the .ism and installer using CmdBld.exe.

Comment: I understand what the ISProg is now, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: IMO InvokeProcess in Workflow is too complicated.  InstallShield supports MSBuild and can easily be attached to a .SLN and built or added to the build definition process parameters as a project to be built.     That said I've pointed out the -z  parameter and I'd appreciate if you'd accept my answer.